# How do I reduce the luminance of this sky without it looking weird?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, mask, smartobject

This is a picture I took yesterday:

[image]

The sky is a bit too washed out for me so I'd like to crank down the luminance of the blue. Camera Raw makes a valiant effort but the crane trusses and other incidentally blue things end up looking...off:

[image]

I opened it as a smart object in PS CS6 to try and mask out the sky but the magic wand tool feels like a club instead of a scalpel when it comes to masking out the bits of sky poking through the crane. Also, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do from there because all the typical level controls are disabled.

How would I go about getting the desired sky in photoshop without the weird fuzziness/coloring on the cranes and buildings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the menu Select-> Color range. Then choose the +eyedropper icon and drag across the gradient of the sky until you have the sky selected. Then go to the Adjustments (under the layers panel) and choose Hue/Saturation, Curves or whatever you want to do with the sky.

[image]

Comment: awesome answer... it's where I would have gone, but you beat me to it!

Comment: @Phlume What I like about it is not just that it would select the sky but also reflections on buildings that contain sky colors. They need to change as well. :)

Comment: Absolutely...and it provides you with full control to tweak the next day when you return as it is an adjustment layer. The only addition I would have done is to save this selection; just in case. Though it is held within the alpha channel of that layer, if the user discards that layer to opt for a different adjustment type, the selection can then be quickly reloaded.

Comment: From a casual observer, the blue curtain on the building in the foreground seems to become more vibrant, is that a side effect of the layer, or of shrinking the screenshot?

Comment: @David, I just did a quick check with a colour picker and the colour of that building hasn't changed (assuming you mean the one the arm of the crane goes diagonally over). In the top image you can see that all of buildings bar a few sunlit patches are black to indicate they won't be selected. It wouldn't be a completely unexpected side effect though.

Comment: @OGHaza The difference is very slight, but its there...  I just scren-capped it and zoomed in on the far left side of the tarps from the two of your images and the bottom image has pixels that are lighter.  However, the difference is so slight, it may just be my eyes playing tricks on me.

Comment: @David, you could well be right, I only selected a pixel in one spot (that was visible in both images in this answer - didn't bother looking at the original).

Comment: @DavidWilkins There shouldn't be differences when we talk about colors that are not present in the sky. I don't know where is the curtain (i don't see one) but if it's sky blue there is a chance it's a sky reflection, therefore it's affected. If it's an occasional similarity it would change and that's the drawback of this method but I think it's a perfect match to what we try to achieve here.

Comment: Since there is a mask involved, it is easy to edit the mask if one needs to limit or expand the effect.